# Text Extraction from a file containing email addresses etc

Tags: linux, extract

How would I extract the email addresses from a file like below where the email addresses are in different columns and then output this to a file

`aaa jim@gmail.com bbb ccc`
`aaa bbb john@gmail.com ccc ddd`
`aaa joe@gmail.com' bbb ccc`

etc

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done, using `grep -o`: the `-o` only shows the result of the regular expression. As far as the regular expression for an e-mail address is concerned, you might try this:

```
grep -o "[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+" filename.txt
```